# Code quotations and Expression trees

Tags: f#, expression-trees, quotations

I wonder if there is any difference in how the two features are implemented under the hood? I.e. Aren't just code quotations built on top of the old good expression trees?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The two types are quite similar, but they are represented differently.

- Quotations are designed in a more functional way. For example `foo a b` would be represented as a series of applications `App(App(foo, a), b)`
- Quotations can represent some constructs that are available only in F# and using expression trees would hide them. For example there is `Expr.LetRecursive` for `let rec` declarations
- Quotations were first introduced in .NET 3.0. Back then expression trees could only represent C# expressions, so it wasn't possible to easily capture all F# constructs (quotations can capture any F# expression including imperative ones).
- Quotations are also designed to be easily processible using recursion. The `ExprShape` module contains patterns that allow you to handle all possible quotations with just 4 cases (which is a lot easier than implementing visitor pattern with tens of methods in C#).

When you have an F# quotation, you can translate it to C# expression tree using [FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator). This is quite useful if you're using some .NET API that expects expression trees from F#. As far as I know, there is no translation the other way round.